# How to switch between several sections in angular component template based on condition

Tags: html, angular, angular-template

I have a couple of sections in my component template file that I'd like to switch between based on certain conditions.

```
<section *ngIf="guest==true">
   <h1>Guest</h1>
   <button (click)="goToLogin()">Login</button>
   <button (click)="goToRegistration()">Register</button>
</section>

<section *ngIf="login==true">
   <h1>Login</h1>
   <button (click)="goToRegistration()">Register</button>
   <button (click)="goToGuest()">Guest</button>
</section>

<section *ngIf="register==true">
   <h1>Register</h1>
   <button (click)="goToLogin()">Login</button>
   <button (click)="goToGuest()">Guest</button>
</section>
```

My component.ts file looks something like this... Initially guest is set to true and the rest of the sections are hidden.

```
public login = false;
public register = false;
public guest = true;

private reset() {
   this.login = false;
   this.register = false;
   this.guest = false;
}

public goToLogin() {
   this.reset();
   this.login = true;
}

public goToRegister() {
   this.reset();
   this.register = true;
}

public goToGuest() {
   this.reset();
   this.guest = true;
}
```

My desired result is such that when a user clicks on a button, the relevant section is brought into view and the rest hidden. The code you see doesn't work. How do I get this to work and is there a better way to do this? I'd really like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't fix your problem as it seems to have already been solved. This instead provides another alternative solution to what you're trying to achieve.  You can also use the `ngSwitch` structural directive which can achieve the same result but in a simpler way.  It'll reduce the logic your `component.ts` file to one method.

#### component.html

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="state">
  <section *ngSwitchCase="'guest'">
   <h1>Guest</h1>
   <button (click)="goTo('login')">Login</button>
   <button (click)="goTo('register')">Register</button>
  </section>

  <section *ngSwitchCase="'login'">
   <h1>Login</h1>
   <button (click)="goTo('register')">Register</button>
   <button (click)="goTo('guest')">Guest</button>
  </section>

  <section *ngSwitchCase="'register'">
   <h1>Register</h1>
   <button (click)="goTo('login')">Login</button>
   <button (click)="goTo('guest')">Guest</button>
  </section>
</ng-container>
```

#### component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {

  public state: string = 'login';

  public goTo(state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

}
```

> https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch
>
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skxolq

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've placed all buttons that switch off/on dependent on them sections (related ngIf directive) inside of that sections:

```
<section *ngIf="guest==true">
 <h1>Guest</h1>
 <button (click)="goToLogin()">Login</button>
 <button (click)="goToRegistration()">Register</button>
</section>
```

And goToLogin should switch off/on `section` (inside of which the button `Login` is placed):

```
// initially it's false
public login = false;

public goToLogin() {
  this.reset();
  this.login = true;
}
```

I guess all buttons that switch off/on related blocks should be out of them like so (also use `*ngIf="guest"`):

```
<section *ngIf="guest">
 <h1>Guest</h1>
 <button (click)="goToRegistration()">Register</button>
</section>

<button (click)="goToLogin()">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking against a boolean, you could just do

```
<section *ngIf="guest">
```

the same for other two conditions as well

Comment: Still no section is getting displayed.

Comment: which means all values are false

Comment: And that right there is my problem. Why are all the values false yet I'm clearly calling methods that set one of the three properties to true?

Comment: i dont see any value of using reset function  as you have initialized all the variables to false initially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**component.html**

```
<section>
        <h1 *ngIf="guest">Guest</h1>
        <h1 *ngIf="login">Login</h1>
        <h1 *ngIf="register">Register</h1>
        <button (click)="goToLogin()" *ngIf="guest || register">Login</button>
        <button (click)="goToRegister()" *ngIf="login || guest">Register</button>
        <button (click)="goToGuest()" *ngIf="register || login">Guest</button>
    </section>
```

**component.ts**

```
public login = false;
  public register = false;
  public guest = true;

  private reset() {
    this.login = false;
    this.register = false;
    this.guest = false;
  }

  public goToLogin() {
    this.reset();
    this.login = true;
  }

  public goToRegister() {
    this.reset();
    this.register = true;
  }

  public goToGuest() {
    this.reset();
    this.guest = true;
  }
```

I hope this will be useful